# ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence when running sklearn adaboost

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm new and python and trying to use machine learning. But my code doesn't work. My dataset is very simple, it contains seven images (without fixed size). I tried to make a segmentation and run the adaboost algorithm but get this error.

```
Error:        
   array = np.array(array, dtype=dtype, order=order, copy=copy)
   **ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.**
```

My code

```
from skimage import data
import glob
import numpy as np
from sklearn import cluster
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
from sklearn.ensemble import AdaBoostClassifier

initDataset = []
samplesListFiles = glob.glob("/home/bv/Downloads/sampleimage/*.*")
i = 0
for fileC in samplesListFiles:
img = data.imread(fileC, as_grey=True)
array = np.reshape(img, (np.product(img.shape), 1))
model = cluster.KMeans(n_clusters=3, random_state=25)
results = model.fit(array[::1])
X = array[::1]
X = results.predict(X)
initDataset.append(X)

dataset = np.array(initDataset)
C = 1.0
X=dataset
y=[[0.],
   [0.],
   [1.],
   [0.],
   [1.],
   [1.],
   [0.]]
rez = []
for i in range(0, len(y)):
   rez.append(y[i][0])
svc = GaussianNB()
clf = AdaBoostClassifier(n_estimators=100, 
base_estimator=svc,learning_rate=1)
X = X.reshape((7,-1))
clf.fit(X,rez)


print "TEST"

cancerListFiles = glob.glob("/home/bv/Downloads/cancerimage/*.*")
for fileC in samplesListFiles:
   img = data.imread(fileC, as_grey=True)
   array = np.reshape(img, (np.product(img.shape), 1))
   model = cluster.KMeans(n_clusters=3, random_state=25)
   results = model.fit(array[::1])
   X = array[::1]
   X = results.predict(X)
   print clf.predict(X)
```

Befor call .fit `X` is

```
  [[array([0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0], dtype=int32)]
  [array([0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0], dtype=int32)]
  [array([1, 1, 1, ..., 1, 1, 1], dtype=int32)]
  [array([0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0], dtype=int32)]
  [array([2, 2, 2, ..., 2, 2, 2], dtype=int32)]
  [array([0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0], dtype=int32)]
  [array([2, 2, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0], dtype=int32)]]
```

Comment: What does your `X` look like?

Comment: i got this output for X before call fit function these arrays are different in size, but i think issue in not here( [[array([0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0], dtype=int32)]
 [array([0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0], dtype=int32)]
 [array([1, 1, 1, ..., 1, 1, 1], dtype=int32)]
 [array([0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0], dtype=int32)]
 [array([2, 2, 2, ..., 2, 2, 2], dtype=int32)]
 [array([0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0], dtype=int32)]
 [array([2, 2, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0], dtype=int32)]]